# Match url.html and url.html/ in Angularjs ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

What is a nice way to match `url` for both `/url.html` and `/url.html/` in Angular.js ui-router?

For now, they are separate like this in my code:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state("myUrl1", {
      url: "/",
      resolve: {
        init: function() {
          console.log("Triggered resolve myUrl1 /");
          return true;
        }
      }
    })
    .state("myUrl2", {
      url: "^",
      resolve: {
        init: function() {
          console.log("Triggered resolve myUrl2");
          return true;
        }
      }
    });
```

I have tried `[^/]*}` in the doc https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing but no success.

Any pointer?

Comment: $routeProvider.when do for both automatically though.

Comment: may be add `[/]*` at the end or if it is regex adding `\/?` should work.

Comment: `^[/]*` doesn't work (not being called at all) and `^\/?` gave me error **Invalid parameter name '' in pattern '/?'**

Comment: ok, its not regex then

Answer (score 0):

> AngularUI Router is a routing framework for AngularJS, which allows you to organize the parts of your interface into a state machine. Unlike the $route service in Angular core, which is organized around URL routes, UI-Router is organized around states, which may optionally have routes, as well as other behavior, attached.

You are asking about how to implement a URL route using a plugin that is not designed for handling routes in this way.  If you are only interested in URL routing, you should use the Angular core `$routeProvider`.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Also, Angular routes don't normally include `.html`.  And, your two example routes `/url.html` and `/url.html/` appear to be semantically the same.

Comment: I am interested in both state and routing. The two examples are more for production vs. development. In production, url is like `/url/` and in development (with light weight Middleman server), the url is `/url.html` instead. I think it should be the same and trigger same state but it doesn't do that. I will check out @YOU RegEx advise.